# Get MAX value in mysql query

Tags: mysql

I have a table

```
       id     mid    userid    remarks
       1       2       8          7 
       2       2       8          6
       3       2       8          4 
       4       2       8          5
       5       2       8          2
       6       2       8          3
       7       2       8          7
       8       2       8          0
       9       2       8          1
       10      2       8          8
```

I need the last row of remark before that row. i.e., remark '1'

```
SELECT MAX(id),mid,userid,remarks FROM sample
```

Comment: You need the remark with the largest or 2'nd largest id?

Comment: Yes Absolutely I need 2nd largest

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
Select Id,mid,userid,remarks from sample Where id<(select max(Id) from sample)
order by id desc limit 1
```

Or

```
Select Id,mid,userid,remarks from sample 
order by id desc limit 1 offset 1
```

Comment: Thank You for your answer. I want to know what this offset do?

Comment: @thersa These LIMIT and OFFSET commands work only in MYSQL. "LIMIT 1" takes first ONE row from result set. OFFSET 1 shifts start row of "LIMIT 1" to the second row. "OFFSET 2" shifts it to the 3'd row...

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
    SELECT MAX(id),mid,userid,remarks 
    FROM sample WHERE id NOT IN  (
    SELECT MAX(id) FROM sample
    )
    GROUP BY mid,userid,remarks
```

**EDIT**

See if this works

[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6c745/2)

Comment: Looks like I misunderstood the question

Comment: It shows #1052 - Column 'id' in IN/ALL/ANY subquery is ambiguous

Answer (score 3):

for **mysql Node.js** developers especially

I was unable to get direct-value in mysql-driver for node.js
i.e. when I run the following query

```
SELECT MAX(id) FROM Users
```

and I got the result as `[RowDataPacket { MAX(id): 1 }]`

I tried to retrieve the value from object `console.log(MAX(id))`, but I couldn't

so I set an `alias` i.e. `maxid`

```
SELECT MAX(id) as maxid FROM Users
```

and got it as `[RowDataPacket { maxid: 1 }]`

Which I can retrieve as `console.log(maxid)`