# select maximum column name from different table in a database

Tags: mysql-workbench

I am comparing from different table to get the COLUMN_NAME of the MAXIMUM value

Examples. 
These are example tables: Fruit_tb, Vegetable_tb, State_tb, Foods_tb

Under Fruit_tb
fr_id           fruit_one          fruit_two
1                  20                 50

Under Vegetables_tb (v = Vegetables)
v_id             v_one              V_two
1                 10                  9

Under State_tb
stateid           stateOne          stateTwo
 1                  70                87

Under Food_tb
foodid               foodOne        foodTwo
1                      10            3

Now here is the scenario, I want to get the COLUMN NAMES of the max or greatest value in each table.

Answer (score 0):

You can maybe find out the row which contains the max value of a column. For eg:

```
SELECT fr_id , MAX(fruit_one) FROM Fruit_tb GROUP BY fr_id;
```

In order to find the out the max value of a table:

```
SELECT fr_id ,fruit_one FROM Fruit_tb WHERE fruit_one<(SELECT max(fruit_one ) from Fruit_tb) ORDER BY fr_id DESC limit 1;
```

A follow up [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11913408/get-max-value-in-mysql-query) for the above scenario.

Maybe you can use [GREATEST](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest) in order to get the column name which has the max value. But then what I'm not sure is whether you'll be able to retrieve all the columns of different tables at once. You can do something like this to retrieve from a single table:

```
SELECT CASE GREATEST(`id`,`fr_id`)
         WHEN `id` THEN `id`
         WHEN `fr_id` THEN `fr_id`
         ELSE 0
       END AS maxcol,
       GREATEST(`id`,`fr_id`) as maxvalue FROM Fruit_tb;
```

Maybe this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12195558/greatest-value-of-multiple-columns-with-column-name) could help you. Hope it helps!

Comment: thanks for your comment, but, i want to get the column name

Comment: so i used the dsc and asc to arrange interms of highest and with the column name as well.....dont know if this is clear enough.